# Getting data in particular format in PHP for Post request

Tags: php, arrays, data-structures

I have to send some data in the below format-

```
$postData = [
            'certExpiryDate' => $certExpiryDate,
            'certType' => 'SSL',
            'AltName' => [
                $altName[0],$altName[1]
            ],
            'csr' => $csr
        ];
```

**$altName** is an array that has 2 or more strings like- domain1.com, domain2.com.

The **AltName** parameter expects the data in this format-

```
'AltName' => [
    'domain1.com','domain2.com' 
],
```

(if I hardcode and send it like this, everything works fine.. this is the correct format)

If I take the array $altName directly like this-

```
'AltName' => [
        $altName 
    ],
```

I did a var_dump and for this it adds quotes outside like- "domain1.com, domain2.com", which it considers wrong.

I need it to be in the format of **$altName[0],$altName[1]** which would be correct, but I'm struggling on how to loop through this array in case it has more values than 2 and still get it in the required format.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the issue is that it's wrapped in single quotes?

Comment: Please show the exact output you are getting and what you expect instead. var_dump() adds quotes around strings that it dumps, thats just how it works, does not mean they are part of the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your attempt:

```
'AltName' => [
    $altName 
 ],
```

doesn't work as intended because it wraps the array `$altName` inside another array (created by the `[` and `]`).

Just set the `$altName` array to be the value of the property directly. There's no need for an extra array:

```
'AltName' => $altName
```

Demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fa3dd6a974be7ced4bdc5d878f692549b96e2b95

Comment: oh man this is embarrassing.. thank you so much for this. I was trying all the possible variations with explode,implode,addslash but this is exactly what was happening, its already an Array and to pass it directly without the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

> but I'm struggling on how to loop through this array in case it has
>   more values than 2 and still get it in the required format.

**posting direct values:**

```
//$altName  = ["domain1.com", "domain2.com"]; 
                //OR 
$altName  = array("domain1.com", "domain2.com");

$postData = ['AltName' => $altName];
var_dump($postData);
```

**output:**

```
array(1) {
  ["AltName"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(11) "domain1.com"
    [1]=>
    string(11) "domain2.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: OP already showed this version in their first code snippet. But the key part of the question is this: `I'm struggling on how to loop through this array in case it has more values than 2 and still get it in the required format.`

Comment: I change the answer. now try it again.